# Why is $f^{-1}(f(x))$ always equal to $x$?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I saw a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262408/if-f-is-invertible-is-f-leftf-1x-right-x-and-f-1fx-x-always) that said that $f^{-1}(f(x))$ is always equal to $x$.
Can anyone explain to me why? I tried googling but the only thing that came close to a proof is this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojLC-0-43ik), but it simply solved the equation.

The equations that made me question this are $f(x) = 3x-2$ and its inverse $f^{-1}(x) = (x+2) / 3$.

Comment: That's the definition of inverse function.

Comment: See this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75365/proof-ff-1x-x/75369

Comment: And this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75365/proof-ff-1x-x?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thanks, these links really clear up my understanding. I'm currently doing exercises about  composite functions and haven't yet learned that definitionally the composite function made of a function and its inverse is always equal to x so.

Comment: "haven't yet learned that definitionally the composite function made of a function and its inverse is always equal to x" Then what exactly did you think the inverse was?

Comment: @RemiKG You're welcome

Comment: @Arthur All we learned about it was that if $y = x^2 - 2x + 3$, then its inverse would be $x = y^2 - 2y + 3$ simplified. With the links above, I can sadly only really partially understand what inverse functions mean, [this one especially helped me](https://mathinsight.org/function_machine_inverse) since it makes a comparison.

Comment: It strongly depends whether $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverseor the preimage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no better answer than the one given on the day that question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have a function $f$ such that $y=f(x)$. If $f$ is *invertible* (has an inverse), this inverse $f^{-1}$ satisfies the property

$$f^{-1}(y)=x$$

We established earlier, however, that $y=f(x)$. This means that

$$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$

where $x$ is in the domain of $f$.

This is similar to [this proof that $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734674/proof-of-ff-1x-x-incomplete).